# Spacy says dependency parser not loaded

Tags: spacy

I installed spaCy v2.0.2 on Ubuntu 16.04. I then used

```
sudo python3 -m spacy download en
```

to download the English model.

After that I use Spacy as follows:

```
from spacy.lang.en import English

p = English(parser=True, tagger=True, entity=True)
d = p("This is a sentence. I am who I am.")
print(list(d.sents))
```

I get this error however:

```
File "doc.pyx", line 511, in __get__
ValueError: Sentence boundary detection requires the dependency parse, which requires a statistical model to be installed and loaded. For more info, see the documentation: 
https://spacy.io/usage/models
```

I really can't figure out what is going on. I have this version of the 'en' model installed:

```
https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_core_web_sm-2.0.0/en_core_web_sm-2.0.0.tar.gz
```

which I think is the default. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem here is quite simple – when you call this:

```
p = English(parser=True, tagger=True, entity=True)
```

... spaCy will load the `English` language class containing the language data and special-case rules, but no model data and weights, which enable the parser, tagger and entity recognizer to make predictions. This is by design, because spaCy has no way of knowing *if* you want to load in model data and if so, *which package*.

So if you want to load an English model, you'll have to use `spacy.load()`, which will take care of loading the data, and putting together the language and processing pipeline:

```
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')  # name of model, shortcut name or path
```

Under the hood, `spacy.load()` will look for an installed model package called `en_core_web_sm`, load it and check the model's meta data to determine which language the model needs (in this case, `English`) and which pipeline it supports (in this case, tagger, parser and NER). It then initialises an instance of `English`, creates the pipeline, loads in the binary data from the model package and returns the object so you can call it on your text. [See this section](https://spacy.io/usage/processing-pipelines#pipelines) for a more detailed explanation of this.